# Django template conditional statement

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the conditional statement below

```
{% if juice.slug != "slug-one" or "slug-two" %}
   rendering things if the page slug isn't slug-one or slug-two
{% endif %}
```

For some reason this conditional statement only works when it isn't "slug-one", instead of when it isn't "slug-one" or "slug-two" .

Comment: This should be `{% if juice.slug != "slug-one" and juice.slug != "slug-two" %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: use `if juice.slug != "slug-one" and juice.slug != "slug-two"`.

The statement `juice.slug != "slug-one" or "slug-two"` is *always* True. Python evaluates the *truthiness* of expressions, and a non-empty string has truthiness `True`.

You are looking for a condition:

```
{% if juice.slug != "slug-one" and juice.slug != "slug-two" %}
   rendering things if the page slug isn't slug-one or slug-two
{% endif %}
```

So you have to repreat the `juice.slug !=` part, and the operator in between is `and`, *not* `or`. If we use `or`, then the statement is still always `True`, since:

```
slug       | slug != "slug-one" |  slug != "slug-two" | with and | with or
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
"slug-one" | False              | True                | False    | True
"slug-two" | True               | False               | False    | True
other      | True               | True                | True     | True
```

So if you use `or`, each time at least one of the two statements is `True`, since if the string is equal to `"slug-one"`, then of course it is not equal to `"slug-two"` and vice versa.